# C++: OpenCV performance issues scanning images

Tags: c++, performance, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I have about 20 images which have been colour coded. I want to scan each image and match the pixel to the label associated with that colour. I have written the code below, however it takes about 30 mins to run to do this seemingly simple task. The images have resolution of 960 x 720.

My Code:

```
void go_through_pixels(path &image_dir, string& ground_truth_suffix, string image_format, unordered_map<RGB, string> colors_for_labels){

    if(!exists(image_dir)){
        cerr << image_dir << " does not exist, prematurely returning" << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    unordered_map<string, set<path> > label_to_files_map;

    //initialise label_to_files_map
    for(unordered_map<RGB, string>::iterator it = colors_for_labels.begin(); it != colors_for_labels.end(); it++){
        label_to_files_map[it->second] = set<path>();
    }

    directory_iterator end_itr; //default construction provides an end reference

    for(directory_iterator itr(image_dir); itr != end_itr; itr++){

        path file = itr->path();
        string filename = file.filename().string();
        RGB rgb(0,0,0); //default rgb struct, values will be changed in the loop

        if(extension(file) == image_format && filename.find(ground_truth_suffix) != string::npos){
            //ground truth file
            Mat img = imread(file.string(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

            for(int y = 0; y < img.rows; y++){
                for(int x = 0; x < img.cols; x++){
                    //gives data as bgr instead of rgb
                    Point3_<uchar>* pixel = img.ptr<Point3_<uchar> >(y,x);
                    rgb.red = (int)pixel->z;
                    rgb.green = (int)pixel->y;
                    rgb.blue =(int)pixel->x;
                    string label = colors_for_labels[rgb];
                    label_to_files_map[label].insert(file);
                    cout << label << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I will be doing more with this data afterwards, but have simplified my code down to this just to try and find the performance issue.

I have found that the `label_to_files_map[label].insert(file)` is causing most of the delay, as when removed it takes about 3 mins to just scan the images. I still think this is too long, but may be wrong?

Also, as the set `insert` is taking a long time (as it has to check for duplicate before insertion) can anyone suggest a better data structure to use here?

Essentially a picture can have lets say 100 pixels corresponding to a building, 100 corresponding to a car and so on so I just want to record in the map `label_to_files_map` that this file (the current image being scanned) has a building in it (which in this case is denoted by a particular rgb value).

Comment: Well, the unordered_map **[]** operator complexity is, in the worst-case, [linear in the container size...](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/). And the set container insert operation is logarithmic. So the whole batch will be 960x720x20 pixels times the complexity mentioned above, in the worst case.

Answer (score 3):

The performance issue is your doing too much work per pixel.

For each file (right before your stacked for-loops start) make a copy of color_for_labels.

```
        Point3_<uchar> oldPixel;
        for(int y = 0; y < img.rows; y++){
            for(int x = 0; x < img.cols; x++){
                //gives data as bgr instead of rgb
                Point3_<uchar>* pixel = img.ptr<Point3_<uchar> >(y,x);
                if(*pixel == oldPixel) 
                    continue; // skip extra work
                oldPixel = *pixel
                rgb.red = (int)pixel->z;
                rgb.green = (int)pixel->y;
                rgb.blue =(int)pixel->x;
                string label = copy_of_colors_for_labels[rgb];
                if(label != null) {
                    label_to_files_map[label].insert(file);
                    copy_of_colors_for_labels[rgb] = null;
                    cout << label << endl;
                }
            }
        }
```

There might be syntax errors (because I re-wrote it in the browser and haven't coded in C++ in a number of years) but the above should cull away a lot of extra processing work.

Comment: Hi, this seems better than my improvement so will delete my answer. I will accept this but will first just edit it to remove some syntax errors and will accept once edits have been approved

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong data types and the wrong functions. Here is a suggestion on how to improve. I suppose it will run in several seconds.

Step 1 of your work is a lookup table from a 3-channel image to a single channel image. you can use cv::LUT. However, you need to do a trick in order to make it fast.

Convert it to 4 bytes per pixel:

```
cv::Mat mat4bytes;
// add 8 bits to each pixel. the fill value is 255
cv::cvtColor(img, mat4bytes, CV_RGB2RGBA); 
// this is a nice hack to interpret 
// the RGBA pixels of the input image as integers 
cv::Mat pseudoInteger(img.size(), CV_32UC1, mat4bytes.data);
```

Now, you can apply LUT.

```
cv::Mat colorCoded;
// you have to convert your colors_for_labels lookup table
// like this: 
lookupTable[i] = 
      ((unsigned int)colors_for_labels.first.x << 24 ) + 
      ((unsigned int)colors_for_labels.first.y << 16 ) +        
      ((unsigned int)colors_for_labels.first.z << 8  ) +        
      255; 
// make sure it is correct!!!
// and lookupTable data MUST be unsigned integer

cv::LUT(pseudoInteger, colorCoded, lookupTable);
```

**EDIT** At this point you have in lookupTable the values you calculate in `label`

The final step of your calculation is actually a histogram. So why don't you use the histogram functions from OpenCV? check the docs for `calcHist()`, and see how it best fits your algorithm. Note that `calcHist()` can perform the histogram of more image at once, so you may want to keep the `colorCoded` images in a vector, then extract the histogram of all of them in one.

Comment: I'm not sure if I need a LUT as I am not trying to change the pixels in the image, rather I am, as you say, trying to build a histogram of specific colours (rgb values) accross the image, where each of the specific rgb values correspond to a label (i.e. building, car, cat etc)

Comment: I have had a look at the docs for calcHist() however it is not clear to me if I can use it for my purpose. For example, is it possible to calculate a histogram over an image where the bins are rgb values {(123,45,65), (144, 44, 89)}?

Comment: The first part of my code converts the (r, g, b) bins into one integer value. Then, with a lookup table, you convert them to your desired label value, and the operation is equivalent to what you are doing until `label_to_files_map[label].insert(file);`. Then, calcHist should be able to do the equivalent of that line, but much faster

Comment: So in the colorCoded Mat I can have strings at each cell? Sorry for the basic questions I am new to both c++ and openCV. Also, I dont seem to have CV_32UC1. I have CV_32FC1 and CV_32SC1

Answer (score 0):

Additional to the other answers with respect to code optimisation, consider working on the image histogram. Several pixels in your image will have exactly the same color so compute the histogram first, then do your processing for every distinct color in your image. That should speed things up greatly